# Why I can not connect to Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to connect my app to firebase but the only response I get is not the response json I need from firebase. I included my call to firebase below. Is the url not correct? The response I'm getting back is not the json object made with firebase that I created.

``

```
<script>
(async function call () {
    console.log("hello")
    const endpoint = url
    console.log(endpoint)

    
    async function initiation () {
    const result = await fetch(endpoint, {mode: "no-cors"})
    const data = await result
    console.log(data)



}
initiation()
})()
</script>
```

``

Comment: Your code is currently ignoring errors inside the `initiation()` call. You should at least be using something similar to `initiation().catch((err) => console.error(err))`

Answer (score 0):

is your database in us-central1?

according to documentation [1]  "the form https://<"databaseName">.firebaseio.com (for us-central1 databases) or https://<"databaseName"><"region">.firebasedatabase.app (for databases in all other locations)."

If its in another region you should try with https://<"databaseName"><"region">.firebasedatabase.app

[1]https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#initialize_the_javascript_sdk

Comment: my database is us central. could any other reason have made my link not working? at least ive ruled out the regional reason.

Answer (score 0):

The structure within your code seems odd, if you are implementing the CDN you need to initiate your app with your project credentials, right now you are only accessing a real-time database as a public request and does not provide any additional validators as the database is most likely to have Security Rules enabled.

To request data from the endpoint, you need to also include a `.json` at the end of the URL `https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/jack/name.json`

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-get